# Query with IF statement

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I have an question about MYSQL If statement.
My request:

```
SELECT c.status, c.thumb, j.id, j.name, j.username, s.session_id, a.time, a.isactive, a.country, a.countrycode, a.city
FROM j16_users AS j 
JOIN j16_community_users AS c ON c.userid = j.id 
LEFT JOIN j16_session AS s ON s.userid = j.id 
LEFT JOIN j16_session AS s ON s.userid = j.id 
LEFT JOIN j16_x5_fastchat_users AS a ON a.userid = j.id 
WHERE j.id IN (62,66,2692)
```

How can I add a new column: isonline with condition to above request:

```
IF(a.time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), "1", "0") AS isonline
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.status, c.thumb, 
       j.id, j.name, 
       j.username, s.session_id, 
       a.time, a.isactive, 
       a.country, a.countrycode, a.city,
       IF(a.time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE), 1, 0) AS isOnline
FROM j16_users AS j 
     JOIN j16_community_users AS c ON c.userid = j.id 
     LEFT JOIN j16_session AS s ON s.userid = j.id 
     LEFT JOIN j16_session AS s ON s.userid = j.id 
     LEFT JOIN j16_x5_fastchat_users AS a ON a.userid = j.id 
WHERE j.id IN (62,66,2692)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it into the `SELECT` list. A [`CASE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) is recommended as more portable though.

```
SELECT 
  c.status, 
  c.thumb, 
  j.id, 
  j.name, 
  j.username, 
  s.session_id, 
  a.time, 
  a.isactive, 
  a.country, 
  a.countrycode, 
  a.city,
  CASE WHEN a.time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isonline
FROM
  j16_users AS j 
  JOIN j16_community_users AS c ON c.userid = j.id 
  LEFT JOIN j16_session AS s ON s.userid = j.id 
  LEFT JOIN j16_session AS s ON s.userid = j.id 
  LEFT JOIN j16_x5_fastchat_users AS a ON a.userid = j.id 
WHERE 
  j.id IN (62,66,2692)
```

Since you just need a boolean 1 or 0, the statement can also be written without `CASE` or `IF` as:

```
 ... 
 a.countrycode, 
 a.city,
 (a.time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) AS isonline
 ...
```

and it will have the same effect.